# How to count based on 2 columns?

Tags: excel, filter, count, excel-formula, countif

Column A is age, 22,23,24,25,etc.
Column B is Heart Rate, 65,66,67,68

Now I want filter:
How many records are there when A=22 & (B>=65 & B<=68)?

How to do it,please? @_@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
=countifs(A7:A10, "=22",B7:B10,">=65",B7:B10,"<=68")
```

Answer (score 1):

For the result line by line please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)
```

in Row 1 and copied down to suit.

For an alternative presentation you might try a PivotTable, with A/B in ROWS/COLUMNS or COLUMNS/ROWS and then either under VALUES as 'Count of'.

Either of the above can then be filtered by your choice of criteria. If you are really only interested in Age 22 this may not suit as much as a formula that 'focuses' on that age, but it can be a quick way to understand the data set better - eg how the numbers in different bands vary with age.

[image: SO38682760 example]

Calculating the result line by line may facilitate charting.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want it line by line try:

```
=AND(A1=22,B1>=65,B1<=68)
```

and you can put that inside an if statement like this:

```
=IF(AND(A1=22,B1>=65,B1<=68),<value if true>,<value if false>)
```